# sqlalchemy dates filter in raw sql

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I used to create dynamic filters  like

```
q = Session.query(Table)    
search_conditions = "%s ILIKE '%s%s%s'" % (str(nm), '%', val ,'%')
q = q.filter(search_conditions)
```

It work ok for string and int statements, but now I need to filter dates the way like this.
I have a date column and trying to filter it like this

```
date = '01.01.2011'
fd,fm,fy = date.split('.')
from_date = dt.date(int(fy),int(fm),int(fd))

ffilter = "%s > %r" %(str(ft), fromdate)
q = q.filter(ffilter)
```

Can you help me with this?

best regards, Sergey

Comment: Possible typo. it should be `q = Session.query(Table)`, not **`qeuery`**.

Comment: @Iwolf: Is the field you want to check, a `DATE` field?

Comment: thanks of course it query... and type is DATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but why not to do the following:

```
date = '01.01.2011'

ffilter = "%s > CAST('%s' AS DATE)" %(str(ft), date)
q = q.filter(ffilter)
```

Comment: thanks a lot man, this is exactly what I need...  I'm using DATE instead of DATETIME and it works like a charm

Comment: You are welcome, Sergei, and don't forget to (down)vote solutions you (dis)like

Comment: Why send this to database: `aDateField > CAST('01.01.2011' AS DATE)`? And not rewrite it in Python as `aDateField > '2011-01-01'`?

Comment: @Artsiom: Are you sure `CAST('05.12.2011' AS DATE)` will be translated as `5-Dec-2011` and not `May-12-2011` ?

Comment: @ypercube I've tried to do this (aDateField > '2011-01-01') before posting here and it doesnot work for me

Comment: @Iwolf: In Postgers docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-datetime.html  you can see that `1999-01-08` is described as `ISO 8601; January 8 in any mode (recommended format)`. There's also the (less human readable) `19990108` which is also ISO format. So, I can't figure why `(aDateField > '2011-01-01')` does not work for you.

Comment: @ypercube I dont know why it doesnot work, anyway I've got an working code, thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

That doesn't look like terribly idiomatic sqlalchemy.  You already have a `Table` object you're using to build your query, you can also use it to express the predicates in the generated `WHERE` clause, even dynamically:

```
date = '01.01.2011'
from_date = dt.datetime.strptime(date, "%d.%m.%Y").date()
q = session.query(Table) \
     .filter(Table.c[nm].like('%%%s%%' % val) ) \
     .filter(Table.c[ft] > from_date)
```

If anything, this is the main advantage of using sqlalchemy.

This pattern extends to almost every corner of sqlalchemy, for instance, if you must specify which *table* to select from in a dynamic fashion, this can be handled by accessing the `MetaData.tables` property, which is also a dict.

If you really need the full generality of expressiveness exposed to the user, you probably will be better served by just allowing them to enter SQL statements, Mixing the generative queries in the style of sqlalchemy with user entered expressions is probably not going to help you or your users.  You could possibly use SQLalchemy to generate skeleton queries and then let users edit them to customize them in the ways they need.

Comment: I have a lot of dynamic filters and I cannot use Table_name object in filter statements

Comment: can you tell us more about the filters you'd like to generate?  You might be surprised just what you can do using sqlalchemy.

Comment: I need to form queries based on data from users, and I dont  know beforehand with which table I should work. Some time ago I already tried to do this using sqlalchemy orm features with no luck. 
In example you wrote "TABLE" is an object and I didnt know a way to provide it using string, also filters (Table.Column) cannot be provided as string
Of course it will be great to liquidate this raw sql statements, if you know how to do this please enlighten me )

Comment: can't find anything about use of "MetaData.tables" dict, can you tell me more about it or give a link where to read?

Comment: It's just a property of the `metadata` object you use when defining sqlalchemy table objects.  you can access all of the tables you've defined using that metadata instance, by name, through its `tables` attribute:  `metadata.tables['foo']`, etc.

Comment: I mean how to construct queries this way. something like tablename = a. colname = b,  q = Session.query(metadata.tables[tablename]).filter(metadata.tables[tablename].c[colname]>10), right?

Answer (score 0):

The filter you want should finally be, (before sent to the database) like this:

```
date_field > '2011-01-01'
```

So, try this:

```
date = '01.01.2011'
fd,fm,fy = date.split('.')
from_date = '-'.join([fy,fm,fd])

ffilter = "%s > '%r'" %(date_field, from_date)
q = q.filter(ffilter)
```

UPDATE: Quotes where missing around `%r`

Comment: Although I'm not sure I understand correctly which string represents the table field and which your testDate.